# Check if type TA can cast to type TB at runtime? (Considering something more than inheritance)

Tags: c#, .net, cil

So I know that this works:

```
class A
{
}
class B : A
{       
}

[Test]
public void CanCast()
{
    Assert.That(typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B)));
    Assert.That(!typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(A)));
}
```

However, let's say those two types were Int32 and Int64.

At runtime, I can cast an Int32 value to an Int64 variable, but not the other way around. How can I check this kind of casting-compatibility at runtime? (IsAssignableFrom doesn't work for this, it always gives false for Int32 and Int64)

**EDIT:** I cannot simply try to cast, because I don't have any value of those types, I'm asking the hypothetical scenario of having two types A and B, not having two values a and b.

Comment: The real question is: what would you do, at runtime, if you couldn't cast your Int64 to an Int32? Either you can work you way around the problem, and then why not apply the work-around all the time so that you don't need to bother about checking, or you can't do anything and then why not let the system throw an exception anyway?

Comment: Is it relevant that some int64 values fit in an int32?  Or do you want to forbid it because it doesn't always work?

Comment: You *can* cast `Int64` to `Int32`, but it's an explicit cast, not implicit. And with built-in types, what explicit and implicit conversions are allowed is language-specific, it's not something you can find out from the `Type`s in question. The question is, why do you want to know this? Why do you want to know at runtime whether an implicit conversion would be allowed in C# at compile time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For non-primitive types, you can reflect and inspect whether there is an `op_Implicit` method on either type supporting the conversion.  IL doesn't actually support true operator overloading, so it's purely a convention system for C# to recognize the operator overloads.  The method will also be marked IsSpecialName if it was created from an operator overload definition in C#.

For [primitive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) (like Int32 and Int64), the simplest option is to hardcode the various cases, as conversion is via a primitive IL opcode rather than via a method.  There are only a handful of primitive types, though, so it wouldn't be difficult to create a method with the check for all possibilities for each primitive type.

One side note since your example mentioned primitive value types specifically, note that the existence of an implicit 'conversion' (in C#) does not mean that all 'casts' will work.  The C# cast operation `(T)x` can also mean 'unbox the value in x to type T'.  If x contains a boxed Int32 and you attempt to (Int64)x, this will fail at runtime, even though you can implicitly 'convert' an Int32 to an Int64.  See [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) for more information as to why unboxing works this way.

Answer (score -1):

One (less-than-elegant) approach is to simply try it - wrap your attempt in a try/catch and Assert false if you catch an exception.

Comment: EAFP paradigm: _It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission_.
If exceptional cases are rare it's usually a good approach.

Comment: I didn't say I have the values, I only have the types.